# How to batch insert incrementing IDs with Hibernate on MySQL?

Tags: hibernate, auto-increment

I am trying to insert n number of records using Hibernate. The criteria will be like getting the MAX ID from the table and to increment the ID and save record. The ID is like `TK020001`.

I got the max ID and incremented for the first record. For the second record it has to take the max ID, but it is taking the previous max. I closed the session and flushed after inserting the first record.

Can anyone give me the best way to insert records for this scenario (MySQL)?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the transaction isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED for your connection.

```
Work w = new Work()
{
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException
    {
        connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
    }
};

session.doWork(w);
```

Don't forget to set the isolation level back to the default one!
In my company we have a little utility class that saves the default level and sets READ_UNCOMMITTED (or any other). When the action is finished we set it back, again with the little nice utility.